# Conversion of a Cold Cathode kit to work outside a PC

Tags: conversion

I have something similar to this [Kit](http://www.directron.com/4inchlight.html)

Now I want to run this off the mains so I will be purchasing a 12V transformer plug. Something similar to [this](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/AC-DC-12V-6W-FIXED-VOLTAGE-400mA-POWER-SUPPLY-ADAPTOR-/190597303940?pt=UK_ConsumerElectronics_PowerAdaptors_SM&hash=item2c607c0e84)

Now my issue the inverter(blue box) takes in some odd connection a two/two pitch connector. I could simply cut the molex connector off this and solder on a connection which would allow the Transformer to be plugged into this.

I'm asking this question with just a vague idea that this will work. I want to know a few things.
Is my logic correct?
What are the risks with this approach?
Am I making a mountain out of a molehill, is there a more obvious cleaner implementation which would yield the same perhaps better results.

Thanks for reading

Edit

This is the Connection to the inverter
[image: This is the Connection to the inverter]

This is a powersupply unit I have have found which may do the job but low Amp output so not sure.
[image]

A list of the specs from the kit.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**ADDED**

Note that the inverter for a CCFL is a very very specialised device. You cannot replace them with anything else "off the shelf" that is not intended for CCFL use. So, you feed them what they want but don't try to replace the actual inverter. So ...

The nameplate says that

- The input voltage is 12 VDC.
- The Wattage required is 2.85 Watt +/- 0.3 Watt.

So you want at least 2.85 + 0.3 = 3.15 Watt, and a bit more is a very good idea. 4 Watt or 5Watt.

Your 12V power supply says 12VDC , 1A.
 Power = V x I = 12V x 1A = 12 Watt = ample!

Your original referenced pictures showed a PC power supply connector,

[image]

which I assumed connected to the 2 x 2 small plug that you now show.

BUT - does yours have the large flat PC connectors shown (4 wires in a line, red-black-black-yellow wiring)?   If not, the notes below make less sense that they might.

A problem is a lack of information still.
 You new photos are better BUT we still don't know your whole configuration.

IF you have a PC power supply connector, see below.

**BUT if the sole power connector is the one you show - How does it get power from the PC?**

---

The "easy and obvious" path (2 choices) is to either

- Add a PC 4 pin power supply socket as per your 1st photo to your 12V, 1A supply and plug the CCFL PC plug into it. Or ...
- cut off the PC plug to the inverter and solder your power supply to the wiring. +12V = yellow (probably). Ground or -12V = black (probably).

The first choice leaves your inverter wiring untouched so that it can be changed back just by unplugging the power pack and plugging the CCFL system into  the PC if required. PC power sockets are very very very commonly available in most countries in old dead PC's or on PC power supplies  or from a computer shop. This is the best choice if you have enough room.

The second choice is very slightly more compact and eliminates a connector pair but otherwise has few advantages and it means you cannot easily change back.

---

Note that connecting power in reverse **may**  destroy the CCFL inverter or the power supply or if you are clever enough, both, but probably not. ie note all voltages colours and connections carefully and draw a diagram of what you intend top do, no matter how simple it may appear.

---

**OLDER** - still worth leaving in:

You should be able to drive this from a suitable mains power supply - that is in fact what the PC power supply is.

Points to consider are

- Which volages does it use?
  PC connector supplies +5V / ground / ground / +12V.
  red / black / black / yellow
  You need to determine whether it uses just +12/ground or just +5/ground or +12/+5/ground.
  I'd expect probably just +12/ground
- The supply has to be "adequate"

  - It has to make the correct voltage without "sagging" or varying "too much".
  - It has to handle startup and restart transient loads which **may** be heavy compared to average load.. May.

You show a 12V 400 mA suppply . 
 That makes 4.8 Watt nominal.

[This page](http://www.directron.com/clk4gn.html) suggests 5ma at 680 Volt for a  300mm tube.
 Power = V x I = 680v x 5 mA = 3.4 Watt.

So your supply would be notionally OK for that tube. But not by a vast margin.
 Startup cu                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            rrent MAY be an issue.
 How well regulated that supply is is unknown.

More soon ...

Comment: Cheers for the response :)
I've added a few more pics and a photo of the specs sheet which should hopefully shed some light

Answer (score 0):

If the connectors are the ones I think you mean (please give a closeup photo) then they are perfectly standard and not strange at all.

These are 5.25" molex drive power sockets to connect go a pc power supply.

Leave the connectors on the invertor alone and get a molex plug to connect to it.  You could either buy new and crimp your own, or use one cut off an old power supply, or butcher a cheap Y connector/splitter.

Comment: Cheers for the response.
More photos added :)